# Measure of disjoint intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is Zygmund lemma 3.15, which proof is left as an exercise:

> If $\{I_k\}_{k=1}^N$ is  finite collection of nonoverlapping intervals then $\cup I_k$ is measurable and $|\cup I_k| = \sum |I_k|$

I found this proof but I don't get the end of it:
[image]

We know that $\overset{N}\bigcup I_k$ is covered by $\overset{M}\bigcup J_n^*$  but that implies
$$|\bigcup I_k| \le |\bigcup J_n^*| $$
And I know $ |\bigcup I_k| \le \sum |I_k|$. But how can I get 
$$\sum |I_k| \le \sum |J_n^*| $$
?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $J_n^*$ contains $I_n$, so $|I_n| \le |J_n^*|$.

Comment: @mathworker21 so that would mean $M \gt N$ always, right?

Comment: I think you might need to take $\epsilon$ small enough to ensure that $M \ge N$. Because then the fact that the $I_n$'s are non-overlapping would force $M \ge N$.

Comment: @mathworker21 alright thanks for your help